# scheduled console command triggered by windows event - variables

Tags: variables, triggers, console, scheduled-tasks

have custom (xml import) created Scheduled task which is triggered by Event. This is working fine.

Just discovered [possibility to transfer Events data to a paramater of started command but in Powershell](https://jigsolving.com/scheduled-tasks-on-event-triggers-with-variables/). My question is if this is possible also for console command for example:

`program.exe -par1 %event_data1% -par2 %event_data2%`

I am unable to find any documentation about this issue. Already performed some blind tries, but have no luck.